# Efficient way to store and retrieve user list for an event feed website

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently developing an event feed website. Part of the concept that's relevant over here:

- Multiple events are displayed on the feed with basic details and a
  'Going' button
- Clicking on the 'Going' button adds the user to the event list. 
  Clicking again would undo  that action.

Right now, I have an **events table** that stores details about events and has a **going_count** column. Another table **event_userlist** has two columns:

```
event_id_count (PRIMARY KEY) and user_id
```

When a user clicks on the going button of an event, the **going_count** for that event is retrieved from the events table, incremented by 1, **concatenated with the event_id** (thus forming something like 4p6ZDpPW9_10) and stored in a variable $eid_count.

The user id is retrieved from session and stored in a variable $uid. 
The **$eid_count** and **$uid** are then inserted in the **event_id_count** and **user_id** columns of the table **event_userlist**. Upon successful insertion, I update the going_count.

**First thing I want to know if I can make changes to make the process more efficient and scalable.**

---

Secondly, while displaying events on the feed, I need to **check if the user is already part of the event's going list** and if so display a cancel button. **What's the best way to go about this?**

Right now I'm planning to retrieve the user list for every event, using the following query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM event_userlist WHERE event_id_count LIKE '$eid%'
```

and then check if current user is in the result of that query. Is that scalable?

Comment: If I get it right, the primary logic is based on having a set of users, a set of events, and determining which users attend to a certain event (and vice versa, as in 'which events are attended by a certain user'), isn't it?

Comment: Yes, there's a set of users and a set of events. But I'm not determining which users attend to a certain event or vice versa over here. You can assume for this question that all users can see all events on their feed. 

The question is concerned with storing the user_ids in the database for users who click on the going button for an event. And retrieving from that list later

Comment: `But I'm not determining which users attend to a certain event or vice versa over here.` If you are storing which users clicked the "Going" button of a certain event, and need to retrieve that list later, you are doing that exactly.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend restructuring your data-storage a bit, and not mashing the count into the actual storage mechanism.

If that's okay, I'd use the table names `events`, `attendants`, and `users`, with each of them having an `id` (primary key), and an `event_id` + `user_id` for `attendants`. These are the bare minimums in my example, the tables can of course have additional fields, although it should not be necessary for `attendants`:

```
+----------+---------------+----------+
|  events  |  attendants   |  users   |
+----------+---------------+----------+
| ID (key) | ID (key)      | ID (key) |
| name     | user_id (fk)  | name     |
|          | event_id (fk) |          |
+----------+---------------+----------+
```

**FYI, this is an N:M relation.**

If a user attends to (clicks "going" button) a certain event, a new row is created in `attendants` with the specified `user_id` (matching the `ID` of the user who is attending), and the specified `event_id` (matching the `ID` of the event that the user is attending).

This way a certain user can attend to any events, and each event can have any number of attending users.

You can then quickly perform a wide variety of actions, **such as**:

Count the number of attendants of a certain event (by event ID, which is 32 in below examples):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `attendants` WHERE event_id=32;
```

Get the list of users attending to a specific event (by event ID):

```
SELECT u.ID, u.name FROM `users` AS u INNER JOIN `attendants` AS a ON u.ID = a.user_id WHERE a.event_id=32;
```

And the list goes on. In short, you can always tell which events a given user is attending to, and which users are attending to a certain event. From that, you can easily tell if an event is attended by the "current" user, count the number of attendants, and so on...

---

**UPDATE**

As discussed in the comments, the `ID` of `attendants` can be optionally skipped, since `event_id` and `user_id` make up a [compound primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) in this case.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Other interesting fields you can put in the 'attendants' table would be 'action_date' which would be the timestamp at which the row was created.  This way, you can show recent activity.

Comment: @Janos Weisz event_id would be used very frequently to identify relevant rows from the attendants table. Wouldn't it make sense to set it as the primary key?

Comment: @AnubhavAwasthy Yes, you are right. In this case, a certain user can only attend to a certain event once, right? We can make `user_id` + `event_id` a primary key, and thus skip the `ID`. This is called a "compound primary key".

Comment: @JanosWeisz Yes, that's right. Stack overflow tells me to avoid comments like thanks. I don't like that. Thanks for the help man!

Comment: @AnubhavAwasthy I appreciate, although the reason this is encouraged is because accepting the answer (cliking on the tick next to it) should be the ultimate 'thanks', and signal as well to other users that it solved your issue. :)